# For loop in Jquery for file validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I built this script below to validate a  tag as soon as a file was added to it. The ID of this tag is "#audiofile". I plan on having multiple input fields (#audiofile1, #audiofile2, #audiofile3) and I don't want to repeat this script say, 10 times to check 10 files. How can I put this inside a for loop and make it check all the fields?

```
$('#audiofile').bind('change', function() {

if (this.files[0].type != 'image/png') {
  $('#audiofile').each(function(){
  $(this).after($(this).clone(true)).remove();
});

$('#message').html('Invalid file type'); 
alert(this.files[0].name + ' is not a valid file type. MP3 Format only.');

} else {  

  if (this.files[0].size > '5000') {

    $('#audiofile').each(function() {
      $(this).after($(this).clone(true)).remove();
    });

    $('#message').html('To Large');  
    alert(this.files[0].name + ' exceeds the maximuim file size.');
  } else {
     $("#audiofile").fadeTo(1500, 0.20);
    $('#message').html('Added');
    alert(this.files[0].name + ' was added successfuly.');
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to each input field and use jquery each loop.

[each description](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$("input.fileclass").each(function( index ){
          $(this)....//reference to input box
});
```